# Is xinetd still the best method to let non root daemons listen on privileged ports?

Tags: security, iptables, xinetd

When I need to use [SNMP monitoring for java applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/snmp.html), there is the need to that application (usually ran as daemon user) to listen on snmp port.

If there is no other alternative, of course I can use another port, say 11161.

But I can use XInetd to redirect port 161 to 11161.

My question is: is this the best method? Is iptables port redirection better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - the Oracle-description sucks. The proper way to use SNMP for an application (java is a application with regards to the operating system) is to register it as sub-agent to the OS-snmp-service (in case of linux: snmpd).

There has to be a way to accomplish that. Afterwards you can use the SNMPD-security settings (see the man-pages of snmpd) to restrict access to that part of the MIB.

Answer (score 2):

In general, `xinetd` is a good solution.  For one-offs, I often use [balance](http://www.inlab.de/balance.html) just because everything can be set up on the command line, but if you need to do it more than once, `xinetd` is a better choice.

Redirection via iptables works just fine, but it suffers from a lack of transparency.  If someone else has to maintain the system, they might be unaware of the redirect rules, whereas proxy solutions like xinetd show up in the output of various standard diagnostic commands like `netstat` and so forth.

Comment: xinetd also has the benefit of generating some syslog entries (for awful apps that don't syslog), shows up in chkconfig (sometimes) and has libwrap support.